# ssh port forwarding through bastion host to Elasticsearch cluster in VPC not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'd like to run some code on my Macbook that accesses one Elasticsearch cluster in a VPC through a bastion host.

Here's my ssh tunnel command:

```
ssh -i ~/Downloads/keypairs/20210402-02.pem ubuntu@ec2-123-456.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com -N -L 9200:https://vpc-123-es-domain-20210406-3abc123.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com:443
```

however, this gives me below error:

```
bind [0.0.35.240]:443: Can't assign requested address
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 443
Could not request local forwarding.
```

added `-v` gives this details:

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-123-456.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/fisher/Downloads/keypairs/20210402-02.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/fisher/Downloads/keypairs/20210402-02.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-123-456.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:7C3VWdZcCglhxtk4ejyayRABeEsVgEMgj+Fp4K3DNFk
debug1: Host 'ec2-123-456.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/fisher/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/fisher/Downloads/keypairs/20210402-02.pem  explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/fisher/Downloads/keypairs/20210402-02.pem
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to ec2-123-456.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com ([54.214.52.40]:22).
debug1: Local connections to 9200:443 forwarded to remote address //vpc-123-es-domain-20210406-3abc123.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com:443
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 0.0.35.240 port 443.
bind [0.0.35.240]:443: Can't assign requested address
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 443
Could not request local forwarding.
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
```

My research points me to add `-4` to force it to use IPv4 instead of IPv6, which is not my case and it didn't work.

Any one could shed any insight as of how to make the tunnel connect?

`Ubuntu` is the root user of the bastion host:

```
ubuntu@ip-11-0-31-228:~$ sudo -s
root@ip-10-0-31-228:/home/ubuntu# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Only root (by default) can bind to ports < 1024. Pick a port higher than 1024.

Comment: my ES service runs on that port 443 which I have to use and I believe my user `ubuntu` is the root per https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/305511/87064, I've also just updated my OP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
-L 9200:https://vpc-123-es-domain-20210406-3abc123.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com:443
```

It looks like your forwarding directive may be malformed. `ssh` is interpreting it as the four-part form like this:

1. Local address 9200 (yes, [this is a valid IP address format](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/inet_addr.html))
2. Local port "https", which is port 443
3. Remote address pc-123-es-domain-20210406-3abc123.etc.
4. Remote port 443

The underlying issue is that you're specifying a URL as the remote, instead of just a hostname. Try this:

```
-L 9200:vpc-123-es-domain-20210406-3abc123.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com:443
```

Comment: Yes! I figured it out also! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It was my own silly mistake after digging more into this and this line gives it away:

```
debug1: Local connections to 9200:443 forwarded to remote address //vpc-123-es-domain-20210406-3abc123.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com:443
```

when it's correct, it'd be something like below:

```
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:9200 forwarded to remote address vpc-es-domain-20210406-3abc123.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com:443
```

two things helped me get this done:

```
1. remove the "https://" in front of the vpc endpoint
2. stop any other local processes that run on port 9200 on my Macbook.
```